# How to pass variables to advice?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

I'd like to pass the "agentArgs" parameter of a javagent to my advice. How could I achieve that?

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(named("org.some.class"))
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) ->
                    builder.method(named("myMethod"))
                            .intercept(Advice.to(MyAdvice.class))
            ).installOn(inst);
}

public static class MyAdvice {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void myMethod(@Advice.AllArguments Object[] args) {
        // agentArgs???
    }
}
```

***Working solution suggested by @Rafael Winterhalter:***

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .type(named("org.some.class"))
            .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) ->
                    builder.method(named("myMethod"))
                            .intercept(Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(AgentArguments.class, agentArgs).to(MyAdvice.class))
            ).installOn(inst);
}

// New annotation to pass the variable
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AgentArguments {
}

public static class MyAdvice {
    // I can read the variable by adding it to the method signature
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void myMethod(@Advice.AllArguments Object[] args, @AgentArguments String agentArguments) {
        System.out.println(agentArguments);
    }
}
```

Comment: `premain` is `static` and probably only called a single time. Don't you think that justifies making the parameters available via static fields or static getter methods? I see no need to make things complicated here.

Comment: the static field doesn't work unfortunately, it seems to not be available when the Advice is used, but there is a working solution below

Comment: I am afraid, "does not work" does not qualify as an explanation. It definitely does work under some circumstances, while under others it does not. It all depends on how you start your agent, which classloader its main class it is in and which classloader the target class is in. If the target class can see the agent class, it works. Otherwise it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide compile-time constants (such as strings) to an advice by binding a custom annotation to an argument:

```
Advice.withCustomBinding().bind(MyAnnotation.class, myString).to(MyAdvice.class)
```

Make sure that the annotation is retained at runtime, otherwise Byte Buddy cannot discover it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Rafael Winterhalter!

Comment: This is a wonderfully elegant way of solving this problem and much more generally applicable than what I suggested. I did not try this, but just reading it is amazing. 